# What does "as good as" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

http://lovefreenovels.com/Fiction/This_Is_Falling/page_44.html
The girl wants to break up with here unconsious forever boyfriend and writes such a say-goodbye letter:

> The more I think about it, the more I know we probably would have
>   broken up by now anyway, because **as good as you were**, we were young,
>   and the me I’m growing into wants to experience more in life.

I looked up "as good as" means "almost, nearly" which seems don't fit into here.

And the uncompleted "you were" means "you were young"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of

> because **as good as you were**

in this context is:

> because **regardless of how good you were**

or even better:

> because **regardless of the fact that you were good**